# What is the correct way to copy data from a postgresql database in one app to a postgresql database in another app on heroku?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I have been following the documentation [Heroku docs on the subject](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#restoring-backups)
and have gone through this and tried variations on what it says to do to for

> Direct database-to-database copies

I am convinced the docs are wrong or I have some setting or somthing wrong (do have admin access). I have also read some scattered things on SO that the command in the heroku CLI for how to do this has changed.

When I run this command (using the credentials for my heroku DB)

```
heroku pg:copy sushi::ORANGE GREEN --app sushi-staging
```

After I confirm the message:

> WARNING: Destructive action
>    ▸    This command will remove all data from

and confirm. Then I get an error that says:

> Heroku PostgreSQL database must be source or target

What is the corrrect way to copy data from a postgresql database in one app to a postgresql database in another app on heroku?

Answer (score 11):

The proper way to do this is:

```
heroku pg:copy [app name to copy from]::[app DB name] [DB to copy to] --app [app name to copy to]
```

So if you want to copy from database 'Orange' on app 'sushi' to database 'Green' on app 'sushi-staging', the command would be what you had:

```
heroku pg:copy sushi::Orange Green --app sushi-staging
```

Most of the time, you will only have one database on an app and the name won't be a color. It will be named 'DATABASE_URL'. You can find your database names in the config vars of the app. I had only one DB, so I had to do:

```
heroku pg:copy sushi::DATABASE_URL DATABASE_URL --app sushi-staging
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Will this destroy/remove the data in `sushi::DATABASE_URL` ?

Comment: @jeanmw No, it will not remove the data in sushi::DATABASE_URL.

I know it is a bit late but I am answering in case anyone new might get into the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

This was seriously not clear from the docs. And sombody at with heroku should make this clear.

```
heroku pg:copy ::DATABASE_URL -a ...
```

You actually write the database as the string representation for the to-database-url but you use the environment variable name `DATABASE_URL`

Comment: Can you clarify your solution? I'm not sure if you mean that the from-database_url should be replaced with `DATABSE_URL`? And what goes in the ... ?

Comment: You define DATABASE_URL as an environment variable, and then you set it equal to the path to your heroku database there. You then literally include DATABASE_URL, and the command heroku pg:copy ::DATABASE_URL -a will automatically map to the defined environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

`heroku pg:copy [origin databasee URI] DATABASE_URL --app [app-name]`

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, resolved by using `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_TEAL_URL` instead of the `DATABASE_URL`:

```
heroku pg:copy postgresql-rugged-XXXX postgresql-closed-XXX -a app-name
```

> *Note:* The two databases are attached here to the same app (`app-name`, in my case).

Now, how do you find the `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_TEAL_URL`? You can find it here:

[image: Heroku add-ons]

Comment: This is the correct answer when dbs are in same app.

Answer (score 1):

The actual FULL command that worked for me, `DATABASE_URL` not being replacement for anything, was:

```
heroku pg:copy project1::DATABASE_URL project2::DATABASE_URL
```

`heroku` automatically fills in the environmental variables.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately copy didn't work for me so I did a backup/restore operation

```
heroku pg:backups:capture --app [source-app]
```

If you run the command below, it will show the available backups from the source-app and its IDs

```
heroku pg:backups --app=[source-app]
```

Get your destination database URL using

```
heroku config:get DATABASE_URL --app [destination-app]
```

Then you create an env var named DATABASE_URL and add the information from the command above

```
export DATABASE_URL='postgres://…'
```

And finally the restore command. (just write DATABASE_URL as this will get the value from the env variable we've created before)

```
heroku pg:backups:restore [source-app]::[backup-id] DATABASE_URL --app [destination-app]
```

---

Update:
Exporting the database_urls for both SOURCE and DESTINATION you can use the below to copy between apps

```
heroku pg:copy [source-app]::SOURCE DESTINATION --app [destination-app]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a different scenario if you're looking at transferring an app from one heroku account to another. You'd probably want to "transfer ownership". This is possible like so:

1. You must ensure that the account receiving the new ownership has a credit-card detail (i.e if the original account has an accrued cost)
2. Ensure you've added the new account receiving ownership as "a collaborator" in the original owners heroku-account. This can be done by clicking on the app (in your dashboard), click on the "Access" tab. Then add a collaborator, by inputting the email address of the heroku-account receiving ownership.

you can follow this guide as well: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/transferring-apps